# What does "should not be a problem" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph which is about how to stop lying. The paragraph has a sentence:

> Avoiding lie to other people **should not be a problem** as long as you understand that you do not have to agree with them on everything for them to like you, that you should not be afraid to say something that could upset them, because people love your candid opinion.

What does "should not be a problem" mean in this sentence? Does it mean "Avoiding lie to other people  **is nothing difficult for you**", right?

Comment: _It's not expected to be a problem_ or _does not usually make any trouble_

Answer (score 1):

It may mean that **it is not difficult avoiding lie to other people , or avoiding lie won't be that big of a problem but an easy task**.